# Setting image height on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I got a problem having a "nice" layout on IE6/IE7 even though I've successfully done it on other major web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari).

So sorry I cannot replicate the error on JSFiddle so here I'm giving the url of the website [here](http://blog-test.koskosan.com.au). In the website I just want to set the height of the three image thumbnails on the right (under In-House Guru section).
I've set the height like the following:

```
.in-house-guru .ihg-thumbnail {
  height: 112px;
}
```

However instead of having the same height, they go with different height. Even worse, when I tried to debug the code through IE developer tools and tried to inject (set) the height directly into the browser, nothing happened.
If I increase the height in the css, say by 500px, they do increase the height too, however they go with different height (eg. 477px, 495px and 120px).

Additional note:
Compass with Zurb-Foundation 3 are used here. Previously there was a problem with the grid because they don't support IE7 and early, fortunately I've managed to fix it using boxsizing.htc script by Schepp.
I tested using IE9 with browser mode of IE7.

Anyone, please help me. It's tearing my hair out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: wat happens if you remove the width and height tags in the html?

Comment: still the same, nothing happened. even after I injected the height directly into the debugger, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the images, it is actually the style for `li`

```
.block-grid.two-up > li {
    padding: 0 5px 11px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

The `padding-bottom` 11px for the first image overlap with the 3rd image in the second row and hence the issue.

Giving a constant padding of 5px for the li like below:

```
.block-grid.two-up > li {
        padding: 5px;
      }
```

Seems to fix the issue for me.

Comment: well, still the same after I changed the the four paddings to be constant. besides where did that 11px come from? it is 8px on my browsers